# how to set middleware in laravel based on user role?

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I am facing a problem with setting middleware in construct().

Every time i the later one is only selected, here the auth as middleware.

due to this my admin is kicked out to login page of user.

and without middleware i am facing problem with lfm as admin is asked to login in the laravel-filemanager window (user is allowed to browse).

Below is my code :
public function __construct()
    {

```
    $middleware = '';
    if(Session::get('user_role') == 'admin'){
           $middleware = 'auth:admin';
        } else {
           $middleware =  'auth';
        }
    $this->middleware($middleware);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the http request or session information in the constructor.

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade (Upgrading To 5.3.0 From 5.2 > Controllers)

Comment: any work around suggestion on the following ? i am currently laravel 5.4.

Comment: Create different routes and define the middleware in your routes.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and did the below:  

Route::get('/web-messages.html', 'DashboardController@getWebMessages')->middleware('auth:admin')->name('admin.web-messages');

still if i log out and visit the page, i am able to access it !

Comment: That would happen if `web-messages.html` a real file in your public directory, then requests goes directly to it without going through php/laravel. Or if you have cached copy. Or a dozen of other causes; like a badly implemented middleware.